# Call FileUpload events from another control

Tags: asp.net, events, file-upload

I have the following code:

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblFileName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
 <asp:FileUpload id="selectedFile" visible = "false" runat ="server"/>
 <asp:ImageButton id ="upload" runat ="server" Height="25px" Width="25px" OnClick="upload_Click" />
```

Is there a way to call the FileUpload's click event so i can select a file?
What I want to do is to create my custom file uploader, and use an existing FileUpload control to help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can call file upload click from another control by using javascript

document.getElementById('FileUpload1').click();

refer this link 
http://cybercalipso.blogspot.in/2014/09/how-to-call-file-uploader-from-button.html